# Почему в django-debug-toolbar ничего не показывается?

Tags: python, django

При загрузки страницы вместо данных выводится следующее:
Данные этой панели больше недоступны. Пожалуйста, перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте ещё раз.

При перезагрузки страницы ничего не меняется. Всё так же ничего не показывается.

**UPD**

Нашел решение сам, вдруг кому понадобиться.
Поменял настройки на следующие:

`DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'RESULTS_CACHE_SIZE': 100,
    'SQL_WARNING_THRESHOLD': 2000
}`

Comment: не могу точно знать за джанго, но обычно схема работы таких тулбаров в других продуктах следующая: при выполнении запроса фреймворк сохранят отладочные данные в какую то папочку на сервере, после чего тулбар обращается либо непосредственно к этим данным, либо к контроллеру который их вытащит и отрендерит в каком-то виде. Если панель говорит что нет данных для отображения, то вполне возможно вы не создали папочку нужную или не выделили для нее нужных прав...возможно конечно например и то что вы напутали и подключили тулбар в боевом окружении...тоже логичное объяснение.

Comment: Пишите ответ в ответе, а не в вопросе